# How to add double quotes to zsh function arguments?

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, zsh

I defined a function in .zshrc as follows:

```
fdtnxg () {
    find $1 -type $2 -name "$3" | xargs grep "${@:4}"
}
```

If I want to use `fdtnxg` to grep `alias mot` in all files whose names start with `tt.` in current directory, I have to use `fdtnxg . f "tt.*" "alias mot"`.

I want to use `fdtnxg . f tt.* alias mot` directly, but couldn't. Is there any way to make it work as I expect?

What I tried to change `fdtnxg` as:

```
fdtnxg () {
    find $1 -type $2 -name "\"$3\"" | xargs grep "${@:4}"
}
```

I tried this because with `echo "\"123\""` I get the quotes `"123"`.

Comment: Note that your `fdtnxg . f "tt.*" "alias mot"` can be written `grep 'alias mot' **/tt.*(D.)` in `zsh` (which also has the benefit of sorting the list of files and report when no file matching the pattern are found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues here, I think.

First, you want to prevent the shell from globbing the wildcard when you run the function. You can't do this by adding quotes inside the function, since the file names are expanded as the arguments to function before it runs. To prevent filename expansion, run the function as `noglob fdtnxg`, which can be automated with an alias (`alias fdtnxg="noglob fdtnxg"`).

Second, the argument to grep. I assume you want the function arguments starting at the fourth concatenated to a single string for grep. `"${@:4}"`, expands them  as distinct words (like `"$@"` does for all positional parameters). `"$*"` instead concatenates the parameters to a single string. In Zsh, `"${*[4,-1]}"` seems to work to concatenate the fourth and later arguments. (`"${*:4}"` would concatenate them all and start at the fourth *character*, this is different from what Bash does.) If that doesn't work, you can always shift the first three out, and then use `"$*"`.

So either

```
fdtnxg () {
    find "$1" -type "$2" -name "$3" -exec \
      grep -- "${*[4,-1]}" /dev/null {} +
}
```

or

```
fdtnxg () {
    local dir=$1
    local type=$2
    local name=$3
    shift 3
    find "$dir" -type "$type" -name "$name" -exec \
      grep -- "$*" /dev/null {} +
}
```

with

```
alias fdtnxg="noglob fdtnxg"
```

In any case, you can't pipe the output of `find` to `xargs` like that. You'd need the `-print0`/`-0` GNU extensions, or better here, we use the standard `-exec cmd {} +` find syntax (adding a `/dev/null` argument to make sure `grep` always prints the file name even if `find` finds only one file; with GNU `grep`, you can also use the `-H` option for that).

Comment: d'oh, I admit to ignoring issues with `xargs`, but where did that `"${*[1,4]}"` come from.. Thanks for the fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what's the meaning of "you can't pipe the output of find to xargs like that."? As `fdtnxg () {find $1 -type $2 -name "$3" | xargs grep "${@:4}" }` worked with `fdtnxg . f "tt.*" "alias mot"`.

Comment: @roachsinai, it will break on any files with whitespace in their names. `xargs` by default splits on any whitespace, so even a space is enough. Let alone the fact that filenames can hold newlines...

Comment: Note that it's not limited to whitespace. single quote, double quote and backslash would also be a problem (and with some `xargs` implementations, sequences of bytes not forming valid characters or two long paths).